Set SCSS variables in "color" file, override in imported "common" file
My company has 4 different SCSS "color files", each relating to a different server environment. I'm upgrading the SCSS compiler in the project and getting a deprecation warning (Sass @import rules are deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 3.0.) so I'm taking the time to update my code now. However I'm getting some errors that I can't figure out how to work around.
_common.scss contains rules like this
.tena-panel {
  background: $theme-light-background;
}

Our "color files" (blue, green, purple) contain variable declarations used by common.
/* from blue-theme.scss */
$theme-light-background: #eaf2fb;
@import 'common';

Which results in the following output after compilation.
/* blue-theme.css */
.tena-panel {
  background: #eaf2fb;
}

However, when I swap to @use 'common'; in our color files I get Error: Undefined variable. from _common.scss during the build process. I've tried passing in the variables to common from each color file using with, but that doesn't appear to help:
@use 'common' with (
    $theme-light-background: #eaf2fb
);

I do want to update to a more modern use case, but I still need distinct "color files" after the build is done, with the same definitions we currently have. Each color file only has 5 or 6 variables so I wouldn't be opposed to changing the setup, as long as I get blue-theme.css when the compilation is complete.

Aha, I figured it out! The problem is that I wasn't declaring default variables in _common.scss. I added this line to the file and now it works perfectly. Here's the final code.
/* blue-theme.scss */
@use 'common' with (
    $theme-light-background: #eaf2fb,
)

/* _common.scss */
$theme-light-background: #eaf2fb !default;
.tena-panel {
  background: $theme-light-background;
}

